# C# values on ASPX page combine on refresh

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net

I'm working on a web page that pulls user scores and takes that score in to a percentage. The percentage is then used to fill a Bootstrap progress bar using the width and aria-valuenow.

The problem is that after the initial build and the page is refreshed, the progress bar widths(aka the scores) grow by the original score. For example if the percentage starts at 40, it will refresh to be 80...120...160...etc.

Here is the C# code where I assign the values:

```
private static string[][] matches = new string[numOfGames][];
private static string[] winningTeams = new string[numOfGames];
protected static string[,] players = { { "Name", "0" }, { "Name", "0" }, { "Name", "0" }, { "Name", "0" }, { "Name", "0" }, { "Name", "0" }, { "Name", "0" }, { "Name", "0" }, { "Name", "0" } };
public static double score_name1, score_name2, score_name3, score_name4, score_name5, score_name6, score_name7, score_name8, score_name9;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    gatherMatches();

    DataTable userPicks = getGSheetData();
    userPicks.Columns.Remove( "Timestamp" );
    userPicks.Columns.Remove( "Your Name" );

    convertTeamNames();

    compareMatches();

    generateUserScores( userPicks );

    score_name1 = Convert.ToDouble( players[0, 1] ) / numOfGames * 100.00;
    score_name2 = Convert.ToDouble( players[1, 1] ) / numOfGames * 100.00;
    score_name3 = Convert.ToDouble( players[2, 1] ) / numOfGames * 100.00;
    score_name4 = Convert.ToDouble( players[3, 1] ) / numOfGames * 100.00;
    score_name5 = Convert.ToDouble( players[4, 1] ) / numOfGames * 100.00;
    score_name6 = Convert.ToDouble( players[5, 1] ) / numOfGames * 100.00;
    score_name7 = Convert.ToDouble( players[6, 1] ) / numOfGames * 100.00;
    score_name8 = Convert.ToDouble( players[7, 1] ) / numOfGames * 100.00;
    score_name9 = Convert.ToDouble( players[8, 1] ) / numOfGames * 100.00;

    name2.Attributes.Add( "style", "width: " + score_name2.ToString() + "%" );
    name2.Attributes.Add( "aria-valuenow", players[0, 1].ToString() );
}
```

Replaced actual name values for the sake of example.

And in the ASPX page:

```
<%@ Page Title="Scoreboard" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Scoreboard.aspx.cs" Inherits="Football.Scoreboard" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div class="page-header">
    <h2><%: Title %></h2>
    <h3>See up to date standings.</h3>
</div>
<p>This page can be refreshed during game time to see changes in leaders as they happen.</p>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3>This Week</h3>
        <div class="progress">
            <div id="name1" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="5" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="16" style="width: 0%">
                Name
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="progress">
            <div id="name2" runat="server" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="16">
                Name
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="progress">
            <div id="name3" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="4" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="16" style="width: 0%">
                Name
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="progress">
            <div id="name4" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="3" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="16" style="width: 0%">
                Jen
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="progress">
            <div id="name5" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="1" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="16" style="width: 0%">
                Name
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="progress">
            <div id="name6" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="16" style="width: 0%">
                Name
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="progress">
            <div id="name7" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="16" style="width: 0%">
                Ryan
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="progress">
            <div id="name8" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="16" style="width: 0%">
                Name
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="progress">
            <div id="name9" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="16" style="width: 0%">
                Name
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have only applied the actions to the 2nd progress bar because the others have no data at the moment.

Comment: provide more code relating to the page ... not enough info here to deduce the issue.

Comment: do you mean more from the aspx page or the cs page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I did figure out the solution. For some reason the 2D array's values were persisting through each refresh, so when I called gatherUserScores( userPicks ); it would add the current score to the old ones, thus growing by the original number.

I solved this by adding the following loop to reset the array every time:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < players.Length / 2; i++ )
        {
            players[i, 1] = "0";
        }
```

I found the reason the values are persisting may be preventable by detecting when the page was refreshed and not running the code again, but I had no luck even with some examples I found, so this method worked out best.

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

I am Inferring a lot in your question but consider these two factors in your code.

**1**  In your **Page_Laod** code you may have to use the Page function **IsPostBack()**
if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Do work you only do on first load 
//Set Progress to 0 and init variables to 0 
    }
else
    {
        // add or do this page load math only
    }

**2** Also Eliminate your static math and page variables for now.

Also: 
   Your second progress bar does not have the percent set to 0 in its html to start with.

Look at your rendered html source when it first loads and when it fails.  This will give you the clue as to where you are having the problem.

*Edit:*

**Static Variables** - I would look to see if you are reading a value from one of your static variables.  Try not to use static variables that you created.  Try to get all your current data from **getGSheetdata().**    Another way to say that is you should have no variables declared above the Page_Load function.  All values should start new with each page, such as 0. *(In this specific case)*  Your next step should be to put a break point on the data change points and watch what happens to your values at each step of your code.

Comment: I attempted to use the IsPostBack method, however it does not detect using the browser's refresh button, only a refresh button I manually added to the page.

What exactly are you referring to as static math?

Comment: Also, here is the source before:
`<div class="progress">
                <div id="MainContent_reese" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="6" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="16" style="width: 40%">
                    Reese
                </div>
            </div>
` and after: `<div class="progress">
                <div id="MainContent_reese" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="12" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="16" style="width: 80%">
                    Reese
                </div>
            </div>
`